# Win 8 UX Design : can we use Rounded Buttons and Box in Design

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, windows-8, user-experience

Win 8 UX / UI Design : 
Can we use Rounded Buttons and Box in Design of window 8 App

I am going to design fro multiple platform so.
I need to design as all device support the design. and 
must be no issue for App stores to accept the app for Design Issue.

Thanks

Comment: All platforms have different design requirements and recommended design patterns. What is appropriate for one will not be for another.

Comment: so how can we design for html5 app that is going to support all platform ? any idea @StevenTrigg